# Match on discriminated union

Tags: f#, enums, pattern-matching, discriminated-union

Using F# for the first time for a production thing and need a little help. Please see this code where I added the warnings I get as comments on each line:

```
type AssetClass = 
    | Corp
    | Corp_SME
    | Res_Mort
    | Qual_Ret
    | Ret_Oth

let Correlation assetClass pd sales = 
    match assetClass with 
    | Corp -> 0.12 
    | CORP_SME -> 0.24 // warning FS0049: Uppercase variable identifiers
    | Res_Mort -> 0.15 // warning FS0026: This rule will never be matched
    | Qual_Ret -> 0.04 // warning FS0026: This rule will never be matched
    | Ret_Oth  -> 0.03 // warning FS0026: This rule will never be matched
```

I checked and it's not bluffing, the third and other cases really are ignored. What am I not getting here? (The pd and sales inputs I do use in the real implementation, I just left out the formulas here.)

What I want to do is use the discriminated union as I would use an enum in C#, and then switch on it. So in C# I would have typed this:

```
    enum AssetClass {
        Corp,
        Corp_SME,
        Ret_Oth
    }

    float Correlation(AssetClass assetClass){
        switch(assetClass){
            case Corp: return 0.12; 
            case Corp_SME: return 0.12;
            case Ret_Oth: return 0.12; 
        }
    }
```

Could someone help me out?

Thanks in advance,

Gert-Jan

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You called your constructor `Corp_SME` but try to match it with `CORP_SME` (all caps). Since this is not the name of any constructor, `F#` assumes it's a variable name (thus the warning about upper case variable names), which then of course matches everything not previously matched (thus the subsequent warnings).

Answer (score 2):

As a side-note, you can also declare `enum` types in F#. To do that, you just add some integer values to the cases of the type:

```
type AssetClass = 
    | Corp = 0
    | Corp_SME = 1
    | Res_Mort = 2
    | Qual_Ret = 3 
    | Ret_Oth = 4
```

To use the `enum` in pattern matching, you then have to use fully qualified name, so you cannot accidentally get the issue you got - you have to write `| AssetClass.Corp -> ...`

You can also get this behavior for usual discriminated unions if you annotate the type with `[<RequireQualifiedAccess>]` attribute. This is probably a good idea as you're not polluting the namespace (but I use it only when I have too many DUs or some conflicting names).

Comment: Hi Tomas, thanks! just as a clarifiation, if I add the integers, it will actually be a .Net enum, so I could use it in a C# project for instance? What if I don't add the integers but keep the code as is, what do I get then? What are the reasons for doing this?

Comment: @gjvdkamp Yes, if you add integers, it becomes `enum` usable from C#. If you don't add them, it will be F# discriminated union, which is a bit more difficult to use from C# (it has a `Tag` property which is some `enum`). The reason why F# uses different representation is that you can have cases with values (e.g. `| Corp of int`).

Comment: Hi Tomas, thanks I looked at the generated code with reflector, not specifying the integers leads to some very different stuff with a nested class for the union with a lot of code. Will stick to specifying the int values. Thanks again!

Comment: @gjvdkamp: Yes, each case of discriminated union is compiled into an inherited class (a case may have different attributes, so DU is represented as class hierarchy). You don't need to worry about this when writing plain F#, but if you want to use it from C#, it is better to expose nicer API (e.g. use F# enum or write F# wrapper class with members)